# Is is possible to add a row to a binding source of the combo box which is data bound

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, data-binding

Is it possible to add a row to a binding source with the following:

```
"Please Select..."   <-- what it will display on the combobox
DbNull.Value   <-- Value
```

I have a combo box which is data bounded to a binding source. I don't want to add an extra row to the database, rather have an option just to display on the combo box so when it reads the above, it sets the corresponding value in the database. Also because there are other combo boxes which use the same data member and data source, so I just want to add the option to that particular combo box.

Above is the contents from the designer file the InitializeComponent() method

```
  this.cmbSecCSR = new System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox();
        this.csrBindingSource2 = new System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource(this.components);
 this.cmbSecCSR.AutoCompleteMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
this.cmbSecCSR.AutoCompleteSource = System.Windows.Forms.AutoCompleteSource.ListItems;
// this.cmbSecCSR.Items.Insert(0, "Select");
this.cmbSecCSR.DataSource = this.csrBindingSource2;
this.cmbSecCSR.DisplayMember = "Name";
this.cmbSecCSR.FormattingEnabled = true;
this.cmbSecCSR.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(112, 26);
this.cmbSecCSR.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(0);
this.cmbSecCSR.Name = "cmbSecCSR";
this.cmbSecCSR.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(184, 21);
this.cmbSecCSR.TabIndex = 2;
this.cmbSecCSR.ValueMember = "Username";
this.cmbSecCSR.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.comboBox_TextChanged);
this.cmbSecCSR.Enter += new System.EventHandler(this.cmbBox_Entered);

// csrBindingSource2
// 
this.csrBindingSource2.DataMember = "CSR";
this.csrBindingSource2.DataSource = this.productionDS;
```

// [image: Check this image]

Comment: Just define another source that simply reference the other source and inserts that row at position 0.

Comment: The initialization of this is done in the Designer.CS....Should it be done there....??

Comment: Cannot provide specifics until you show what the CompboBoxes are bound to.

Comment: "What the CompboBoxes are bound to"?  What is csrBindingSource2 and how is it populated.

Comment: CsrBindingSource references a Datasheet ProductionDS where there is a Data table called CSR

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27894/discussion-between-masa-rumi-and-blam)

Answer (score 0):

Try this sample way.

Markup:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddljobcategory" CssClass="txtborder" Width="175px" runat="server" Height="20px" >
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Code-behind:

```
DataView dvProduct = new DataView();
dvProduct = objcategory.GetCategoryType();
ddljobcategory.DataTextField = "CatName";
ddljobcategory.DataValueField = "CatId";
ddljobcategory.DataSource = dvProduct;
ddljobcategory.DataBind();
ddljobcategory.Items.Insert(0, "Select");//**Add your content instead of Select**
ddljobcategory.Items[0].Value = "0";
```

It's displayed like this:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Since the question refers to binding I don't think it is ASP.NET

Answer (score 0):

If you use SQL to create your DataView UNION a SELECT statement that contains your desired values:

```
          SELECT Rule_Number, Title FROM Rules 
          UNION
          SELECT '', '<Select>'
          ORDER BY 2
```

Comment: That will not work because that same select statement table is used for other bindings...and plus there are multiple values being selected and displayed based on the Office Location and etc.